# sin with taylor series in python

Tags: python, trigonometry, taylor-series

This is my code :

```
import math    
x=float(( input ('x ? ' )))  
n  = 1000   #a big number 
b=0      
for i in range (n):    
   a=(((((-1)**i))*(x**((2*i)+1)))/(math.factorial((2*i)+1)))   
   b+=a     
print (b)
```

but it doesn't work and shows this error:

```
"OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float"
```

Comment: What's the question? `math.factorial(1999)` *is* too large to convert to a float. It is approximately 10^5733. The max value of `float` is `sys.float_info.max`, which I'll wager is about 10^308 on your system.

Comment: you can compute the `a`s using recursion: `a[i] = -a[i-1] x**2 / 2i / (2i + 1)`

Comment: @SteveJessop   for examaple when i want to compute sin 30
my input is 0.523 .
but it show the "OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float"

Comment: @RuggeroTurra  did you see my last comment here ?!

Comment: The input is irrelevant, your code computes `factorial(1999)` (as well as a bunch of other numbers that are too big to convert to `float`) regardless of the input value. When you divide a `float` by an integer, Python tries to convert the integer to a float. It fails.

Answer (score 2):

This is just for plotting:

```
import numpy as np
vmysin = np.vectorize(mysin, excluded=['order'])

x = np.linspace(-80, 80, 500)
y2 = vmysin(x, 2)
y10 = vmysin(x, 10)
y100 = vmysin(x, 100)
y1000 = vmysin(x, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, y, label='sin(x)')
plt.plot(x, y2, label='order 2')
plt.plot(x, y10, label='order 10')
plt.plot(x, y100, label='order 100')
plt.plot(x, y1000, label='order 1000')
plt.ylim([-3, 3])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot sin x]

It suffers from numerical instability and underflow, since after a while (~100 loops, depending on `x`) `a` becomes 0.

Answer (score 1):

correct answer of sine taylor series

```
# calculate sin taylor series by using for loop in python
from math import*

print "sine taylor series is="

x=float(raw_input("enter value of x="))

for k in range(0,10,1):
    y=((-1)**k)*(x**(1+2*k))/factorial(1+2*k)

    print y
```

Comment: The taylor series is a sum so you need to initialize your y to zero and add `y += ...` in the loop.  Otherwise, aside from a couple typos, it looks good.

Comment: In the line `y=((-1)**k)*(x**(1+2*k))/factorial(1+2*k)` you need to change to `y= y + ( (-1)**k) * (x**(1+2*k) ) / factorial(1+2*k)` and this way will work. Awesome onliner!

Comment: @ElbertVillarreal you need to initialize `y` then.

Comment: Sure Boris, just want to improve the line. The Taylor Series is no a easy task and this line help so much to understand.